# Yesterday's date in SSIS package setting in variable through expression

Tags: ssis, msbi

I am setting a variable in `SSIS` package and I'm using this expression:

```
DATEPART("yyyy", GETDATE())*10000 
        + DATEPART("month", GETDATE())*100  
        + DATEPART("day",GETDATE())
```

The expression will give me a variable value like 'yyyymmdd'. My problem is that I want yesterday's date.

For example on 11/1/2014 it should be 20141031

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `DATEADD` function 
your expression would be :

```
DATEPART("yyyy", DATEADD( "day",-1, GETDATE()))*10000 + DATEPART("month",  DATEADD( "day",-1, GETDATE())) * 100 + DATEPART("day", DATEADD( "day",-1, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 6):

This will give yesterday's date

`(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(DATEADD("day",-1,GETDATE()))
+RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("MM", DATEADD("day", -1, GETDATE())),2)
+RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("DD", DATEADD("day", -1, GETDATE())),2)`

Answer (score 3):

less code...

```
CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()),112)
```

Comment: This doesn't work in an expression - at least not in version 10 (Visual Studio 2008)

Answer (score 0):

The following example gives the date yesterday with hours and minutes: 
2015-09-06-14-40

```
(DT_WSTR, 4) Year(dateadd("day",-1,getdate())) +  "-" 
+ ( month(dateadd("day",-1,getdate())) < 10 ? "0" + (DT_WSTR, 4) month(dateadd("day",-1,getdate())):(DT_WSTR, 4) month(dateadd("day",-1,getdate()))) 
+ "-" +( day(dateadd("day",-1,getdate())) <10 ? "0" + (DT_WSTR, 4) day(dateadd("day",-1,getdate())):(DT_WSTR, 4) day(dateadd("day",-1,getdate()))) 
+ "-" + right("0"+(DT_WSTR,4)datepart("hh",getdate()),2) 
+ "-" + right("0"+(DT_WSTR,4)datepart("mi",getdate()),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(GETDATE()) +RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(GETDATE()),2) +RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("DD", DATEADD("day", -1, GETDATE())),2)
```

Above will also give you date one day before. Main issue issue doing plus or minus gives truncation error in expression.

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART("DD", DATEADD("day", -1, GETDATE())),2)
```

will not break the expression.