# SSIS expression previous date without DateAdd()

Tags: sql-server, string, datetime, variables, ssis

Currently developing a package that passes an expression from a previous date to a filename. The current code I have is the following as a string variable:

> (DT_WSTR,20)DATEPART("YYYY",Dateadd("DD",-1,dateadd("MM",datediff("MM",
>   (DT_DATE) "1900-01-01",getdate())-2, (DT_DATE) "1900-01-01")))
>   + RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR,20)DATEPART("MM",Dateadd("DD",-1,dateadd("MM",datediff("MM", (DT_DATE) "1900-01-01",getdate())-5, (DT_DATE) "1900-01-01"))),2)
>   + "01"

This currently produces the output of:

> 20171101

This is currently incorrect because I'd like the date to be from the previous year:

> 20161101

Here's the forumula I'd like:

Return the 1st day of the month that is 7 months in the past from today's date.

Example: 5/2/2017 would return 11/1/2017; 6/21/2017 would return 12/1/2016; 7/10/2017 would return 1/1/2017; etc.

Is this possible to do via a variable in SSIS?

Comment: Should be easy to alter your existing expression - just `DATEADD` -1 month on the year and month part and hardcode `1` for the day part.

Comment: Your first example seems wrong - did you mean 5/2/2017 would return 11/1/201**6**?

Comment: The string variable above produces a date that is 7 months in the past, however the year is still the current year. I'm trying to have it produce a true date 7 months in the past.

Comment: If being **7** months in the past, shouldn't your results be 5/2/2017 **->** 10/1/2016, 6/21/2017 **->** 11/1/2017 and 7/10/2017 **->** 12/1/2016?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression can be modified (and simplified) to this

```
(DT_WSTR, 8)( ( YEAR( DATEADD( "MM", -7, GETDATE() ) ) * 10000 ) + ( MONTH( DATEADD("MM", -7, GETDATE() ) ) * 100 ) + 1 )
```

- subtract 7 months from current date
- multiply resulting year by 10000
- subtract 7 months from current date
- multiply resulting month by 100
- add year-value, month-value and 1 (first day)
- convert to string

---

Credit to @Rangani in [Yesterday's date in SSIS package setting in variable through expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26841952/205233) for "multiply and add instead of string concat" trick

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD("MM", -6, '2017-05-02'), 112), 6) + '01'
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD("MM", -6, '2017-06-21'), 112), 6) + '01'
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD("MM", -6, '2017-07-10'), 112), 6) + '01'
```