# SQL Convert data time format (yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000) to yyyymmdd as int

Tags: sql

It must be very simple, but I don't know SQL language very well.
I need to filter data by date which is in this format:

[image]

How to do it right to filter data this way?

```
FROM [TableName] where
FileDate>=20220505
```

I've already tried the command LEFT and CAST but with no success

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an integer representation of your datetime by multiplying and adding the date parts:

```
year  * 10000    20220000
month * 100           500
day                     5
-------------------------
                 20220505
```

```sql
...
FROM [TableName]
WHERE (DATEPART(year, [FileDate]) * 10000) + (DATEPART(month, [FileDate]) * 100) + (DATEPART(day, [FileDate])) >= 20220505
```

However I'd still look into fixing the condition input format instead.

---

Credit to @Rangani in [Yesterday's date in SSIS package setting in variable through expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26841952/205233) for "multiply and add instead of string concat" trick

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work:

```
declare  @now Datetime = getdate();
declare  @intNow int = cast(cast(datepart(year, @now) as varchar(4)) + RIGHT('00'+CAST(datepart(month, @now) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + RIGHT('00'+CAST(datepart(day, @now) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) as int)
```

Although if you have your date to check against in the right format e.g. using:

```
declare @dateToCheck Datetime = cast(cast(20220505 as varchar) as datetime)
```

And then

FileDate>= @dateToCheck

it should work

Comment: Thank you @CF5 ! Maybe now, I will start to learn SQL language ;) It is very clear!